# Is there a concept of "parallel/alternate" universes/realities in Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, parallel-universe

Star Trek franchise has concepts of parallel (or alternate) universes/realities. So does StarGate (in some SG1 episodes).

**Is there any mention of such a concept as parallel universes in Star Wars canon?**

The question is restricted to G,T, C and at the worst case S-canon.

Also, the general handwavy "always in motion, the future is" is not what I have in mind – I mean an actual specific parallel universe, somewhat or completely different from "main" one, being mentioned as part of the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Hyperspace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace) is an alternate dimension.

> **Hyperspace was an alternate dimension** that could only be reached by traveling at lightspeed or faster. By entering hyperspace, a starship could take advantage of the wrinkles in the fabric of realspace to reduce journey time significantly, "jumping" from a specific point to another point without having to travel directly between them

It features in all levels of canon.

Comment: @dvk-in-exile Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

To some degree, yes, there is mention of it in the extended universe canon.

In the (now almost separated from canon) West End Games *Star Wars: The Role Playing Game*, several alternate dimensions are mentioned, not as parallels in the "alternate earths" sense, but definitely parallels where time, space, and location overlap, but the specific contents don't.

The Otherspace and Otherspace II modules for that game make extensive use of one such alternate.

There are also hints of it in a couple of novels, but nothing terribly explicit that I recall (but I quit reading SW novels in the early 1990s).

Comment: Are those Otherspace  RPGs canon (other than N?)

Comment: They were approved by Lucas. Even the modules had to go through the full approval process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Waru's universe fits into that concept, as well as Timeshadows. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeshadow.

Comment: Are those Living Force RPGs canon (other than N?)